# Don't change ajax URL when application URL changes

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I working on a MVC project. I am calling my ActionResult from jquery ajax as

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveCustomer","Customer")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(customerViewModel),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert('Customer saved successfully');                 
        }
    });
```

This code works as expected when the code was located in /cshtml page. I want to move this code to a separate js file.
   Now, the "@Url.Action" will not work here, so I replaced the url as '/Customer/SaveCusomer'
  This also works perfectly when I hosted the application in below format:

```
http://localhost:12345/Customer
```

But I want to host the application like below

```
 http://localhost:12345/ApplicationName/Customer
```

What happened is, '/Customer/SaveCusomer' is not working .

So how to make the ajax URL to work with both host URL's

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, and solve via add a global variable for keep root path in layout.cshtml page. and use this variable in other places.

```
<script>
        APPLICATION_PATH = '@Url.Content("~/")';
</script>
```

in js file :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: APPLICATION_PATH + "Company/Update",
        data: JSON.stringify(_company),
        contentType: "application/json",
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (response) {

        },
        error: function (response) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Musthaan